# How do I include an argument based on a condition (in CoffeeScript/JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dry, coffeescript, google-analytics-api

I've written a CoffeeScript function that resembles this contrived example:

```
my_func = (a, b, use_args = false) ->
  if use_args?
    other_func 'foo', a, b, 'bar'
  else
    other_func 'foo', 'bar'
```

This compiles to the following JavaScript:

```
var my_func;
my_func = function(a, b, use_args) {
  if (use_args == null) {
    use_args = false;
  }
  if (use_args != null) {
    return other_func('foo', a, b, 'bar');
  } else {
    return other_func('foo', 'bar');
  }
};
```

Is there a DRY approach to this function that would eliminate the duplicate call to `other_func`? Something like:

```
my_func = (a, b, use_args = false) ->
  other_func 'foo', a if use_args?, b if use_args?, 'bar'
```

but that's actually syntactically correct? Hopefully I'm not missing something obvious here.  I'm not sure if CoffeeScript provides a handy way to do this, or if there's just a better JavaScript pattern I should be using.

Incidentally, I can't modify `other_func` to use different parameters, since it's actually `_gaq.push()`, part of the Google Analytics library that adds tracking information to a queue.

Comment: So, you noticed that because your code starts with `if (use_args == null) use_args = false`, the `use_args?` condition will always be `true`... right?

Comment: Good point - I hadn't thought that through. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I think the code in your original question is fine (other than the `= false` in the argument list—see my comment). It's perfectly efficient and readable. But if the repetition really bothers you, read on.

Chris is on the right track in his answer. Since this is CoffeeScript, there are some syntactic sugars you can take advantage of:

- Instead of `arr.splice(1, 0, [a, b])`, you can write `arr[1...1] = [a, b]`.
- Instead of `func.apply(null, arr)`, you can simply write `func arr...`.

So, combining those, you can get your function down to 3 short, repetition-free lines:

```
my_func = (a, b, use_args) ->
  args = [foo, bar]
  args[1...1] = [a, b] if use_args
  other_func args...
```

Notice that you don't have to do a `use_args?` check; if it's `null` or `undefined`, it'll be coerced to `false` automatically (by JavaScript) for `if use_args`.

Comment: Thanks, Trevor - great answer, that's exactly what I was looking for. From the guy who wrote the book on the subject, no less. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of:

- [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to inject the additional parameters in to an array of params, and
- [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call the function with an array of parameters.

Here's a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZSVtB/

Comment: Thanks, Chris! Good answer and I appreciate the code snippet. I had to favor Trevor's answer just because it's more CoffeeScript-centric, which I was hoping for.

Comment: No worries. I don't know much coffeescript, but the nifty tricks in Trevor's answer piques my interest :)

Comment: I just started to pick up CoffeeScript a couple weeks ago, and I'm really enjoying it. It's very well documented at sites like http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/, http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/, http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/, and http://autotelicum.github.com/Smooth-CoffeeScript/. It accentuates the best of JS and eliminates a lot of boilerplate code; also facilitates classical object-oriented structure if that's your thing (I've found that it cleans up my code substantially). I'd also highly recommend Trevor's book - it's well-written and is a great primer.

Answer (score -1):

```
var my_func = function(a, b, use_args) { 
  var args = []
  args.push('foo')
  use_args && args.push(a, b)
  args.push('bar')
  return other_func.apply(null, args)
}
```

Okay, no `with` from now on.

Comment: I can't believe someone just wrote code and used `with` in it. It's explicitly forbidden in ES5 Strict.

Comment: I can't believe you can't believe.

Comment: Thanks, SomeGuy - I appreciate your input. I think it's generally a good approach and while I was also going to mention the use of `with`, I wouldn't have been as rude about it as the other commenters. ;-)